# JavaScript: Transform from one nested JSON format to another nested JSON format

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, recursion, transformation

I am trying to transform an AVRO schema into an ElasticSearch index template. Both are JSON structured with a few things to check while transforming. I tried using recursion to get all the nested elements out and then pair them with their parents but writing to a dictionary while parsing deep with recursion compelled me to ask this question.

So basically I have this AVRO schema file:

```
{
    "name": "animal",
    "type": [
        "null",
        {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "zooAnimals",
            "fields": [{
                    "name": "color",
                    "type": ["null", "string"],
                    "default": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "skinType",
                    "type": ["null", "string"],
                    "default": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "species",
                    "type": {
                        "type": "record",
                        "name": "AnimalSpecies",
                        "fields": [{
                                "name": "terrestrial",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "aquatic",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "behavior",
                    "type": [
                        "null",
                        {
                            "type": "record",
                            "name": "AnimalBehaviors",
                            "fields": [{
                                    "name": "sound",
                                    "type": ["null", "string"],
                                    "default": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "hunt",
                                    "type": ["null", "string"],
                                    "default": null
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "default": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and I would like it to get transformed into this (Elasticsearch index template format):

```
{
    "properties": {
        "color" :{
            "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "skinType" :{
            "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "species" :{
            "properties" : {
                "terrestrial" : {
                    "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "aquatic" : {
                    "type" : "keyword"
                },
            }
           
        },
        "behavior" : {
            "properties" : {
                "sound" : {
                    "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "hunt" : {
                    "type" : "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Important Notes: The nesting on the AVRO schema could be furthermore nested and that's why I was thinking recursion to solve. Also, the type of the `type` filed could be an `Array` or a `Map` as shown for `behavior` vs. `species` where behavior has an array and species has a map.

If you must see that I did my trial and error, here's my code that's not getting me anywhere:

```
const checkDataTypeFromObject = function (obj) {

  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Array]") {
    obj.map(function (item) {
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(item) === "[object Object]") {
        // so this is an object that could contain further nested fields
        dataType = item;
        mappings.properties[item.name] = { "type" : item.type}
         if (item.hasOwnProperty("fields")) {
          checkDataTypeFromObject(item.fields);
        } else if (item.hasOwnProperty("type")) {
          checkDataTypeFromObject(item.type);
        } 
      } else if (item === null) {
        // discard the nulls, nothing to do here
      } else {
        // if not dict or null, this is the dataType we are looking for
        dataType = item;
      }

      return item.name
    });
```

Comment: The input JSON doesn't correspond to a valid AVRO schema. Look at {"name":"animal","type":["null",{.... There are no objects in the field "type". A type is string or an array of strings and the string value is one of these: null, int, long, float, double, bytes, string, record, enum, array, map or fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can break it down using inductive reasoning. The numbered points below correspond the the numbered comments in the code -

1. if the input, `t`, is null, return an empty object
2. (inductive) `t` is not null. If `t.type` is an object, `transform` each leaf and sum into a single object
3. (inductive) `t` is not null and `t.type` is not an object. If `t.fields` is an object, `transform` each leaf, assign to `{ [name]: ... }`, and sum into a single *properties* object
4. (inductive) `t` is not null and `t.type` is not an object, and `t.fields` is not an object. Return *keyword*.

```js
const transform = t =>
  t === "null"
    ? {}                           // <- 1
: isObject(t.type)
    ? arr(t.type)                  // <- 2
        .map(transform)
        .reduce(assign, {})
: isObject(t.fields)
    ? { propertries:               // <- 3
          arr(t.fields)
            .map(v => ({ [v.name]: transform(v) }))
            .reduce(assign, {})
      }
: { type: "keyword" }              // <- 4
```

With a few helpers to keep complexity out of our way -

```js
const assign = (t, u) =>
  Object.assign(t, u)

const arr = t =>
  Array.isArray(t) ? t : [t]
  
const isObject = t =>
  Object(t) === t
```

Simply run the `transform` -

```js
console.log(transform(input))
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the result in your browser -

```js
const assign = (t, u) =>
  Object.assign(t, u)

const arr = t =>
  Array.isArray(t) ? t : [t]
  
const isObject = t =>
  Object(t) === t

const transform = t =>
  t === "null"
    ? {}
: isObject(t.type)
    ? arr(t.type)
        .map(transform)
        .reduce(assign, {})
: isObject(t.fields)
    ? { propertries:
          arr(t.fields)
            .map(v => ({ [v.name]: transform(v) }))
            .reduce(assign, {})
      }
: { type: "keyword" }

const input =
  {name: "animal", type: ["null", {type: "record", name: "zooAnimals", fields: [{name: "color", type: ["null", "string"], default: null}, {name: "skinType", type: ["null", "string"], default: null}, {name: "species", type: {type: "record", name: "AnimalSpecies", fields: [{name: "terrestrial", type: "string"}, {name: "aquatic", type: "string"}]}}, {name: "behavior", type: ["null", {type: "record", name: "AnimalBehaviors", fields: [{name: "sound", type: ["null", "string"], default: null}, {name: "hunt", type: ["null", "string"], default: null}]}], default: null}]}]}

console.log(transform(input))
```

Output -

```
{
  "propertries": {
    "color": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "skinType": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "species": {
      "propertries": {
        "terrestrial": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "aquatic": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "behavior": {
      "propertries": {
        "sound": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "hunt": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**nota bene**

In *step 2* we could have a complex `type` such as -

```js
{ name: "foo"
, type: [ "null", { obj1 }, { obj2 }, ... ]
, ...
}
```

In such a case, `obj1` and `obj2` may each `transform` into a `{ properties: ... }` object. Using `.reduce(assign, {})` means properties of `obj1` will be overwritten by properties of `obj2` -

```js
: isObject(t.type)
    ? arr(t.type)
        .map(transform)
        .reduce(assign, {})   // <- cannot simply use `assign`
```

To remedy this, we change step 2 to `merge` complex types more intelligently -

```js
: isObject(t.type)
    ? arr(t.type)
        .map(transform)
        .reduce(merge, {})   // <- define a more sophisticated merge
```

Where `merge` could be something like -

```js
const merge = (t, u) =>
  t.properties && u.properties // <- both
    ? { properties: Object.assign(t.properties, u.properties) }
: t.properties                 // <- only t
    ? { properties: Object.assign(t.properties, u) }
: u.properties                 // <- only u
    ? { properties: Object.assign(t, u.properties) }
: Object.assign(t, u)          // <- neither
```

Or the same `merge` but using a different logical approach -

```js
const merge = (t, u) =.
  t.properties || u.properties    // <- either
    ? { properties:               
          Object.assign
            ( t.properties || t
            , u.properties || u
            )
      }
    : Object.assign(t, u)         // <- neither
```

Comment: Nice work, as always.  It's interesting to see the different choices we have made to signal our different cases.  Mine could do well with a dose of helper functions (posted too close to bedtime!).  But there's some fundamental differences too -- you merge the results of every element in a `type` array, where I take only the second.  I know nothing about the ARVO schema, but from this sample, I'm not impressed.

Comment: Thank you, fantastic solution!

Comment: @ScottSauyet I agree with you.. I created the sample so that the question doesn't become too long as well as its brief enough to cover my most important possible cases. Thank you for your time ;) Also, the AVRO specs is a mess and is way too verbose than it should be in my opinion.

Comment: @Thank you, what if the field array had records that had additional attribute, something like `{"data_type: { "type" : "animal"}}` and your inductive reason 4 is based on this object? How does the code change then?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your input format nor your output one.  So this is probably incomplete.  It captures your sample case, though, and it might serve as a baseline to which you can add clauses/conditions:

```js
const convertField = ({name, type, fields}) =>
  Array .isArray (type) && type [0] === 'null' && type [1] === 'string'
    ? [name, {type: 'keyword'}]
  : Array .isArray (type) && type [0] === 'null' && Object (type [1]) === type [1]
    ? [name, {properties: Object .fromEntries (type [1] .fields .map (convertField))}]
  : Object (type) === type
    ? [name, {properties: Object .fromEntries (type .fields .map (convertField))}]
  : // else 
      [name, {type: 'keyword'}]

const convert = (obj) =>
  convertField (obj) [1]

const input = {name: "animal", type: ["null", {type: "record", name: "zooAnimals", fields: [{name: "color", type: ["null", "string"], default: null}, {name: "skinType", type: ["null", "string"], default: null}, {name: "species", type: {type: "record", name: "AnimalSpecies", fields: [{name: "terrestrial", type: "string"}, {name: "aquatic", type: "string"}]}}, {name: "behavior", type: ["null", {type: "record", name: "AnimalBehaviors", fields: [{name: "sound", type: ["null", "string"], default: null}, {name: "hunt", type: ["null", "string"], default: null}]}], default: null}]}]}

console .log (convert (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The helper function, `convertField`, converts one field of your input into the format `[name, <something>]`, where the `<something>` varies by the structure of the `type` property.  In two cases we use an array of these structures as input to `Object .fromEntries` in order to create an object.

The main function, `convert`, simply grabs the second property off the result of `convertField` called on the root.  That works if the overall structure always starts as it does in this example.

Note that the results of two of the clauses (the first and the fourth) are identical, and the other two are quite similar to one another.  Also the tests for the first and second clauses are quite close.  So there might be some reasonable ways to simplify this.  But because the matching tests don't line up well with the matching output, it probably won't be trivial.

You can add other conditions and results easily enough.  In fact, I originally wrote it with the final two lines replaced by this:

```js
  : type === 'string'
    ? [name, {type: 'keyword'}]
  : // else 
      [name, {type: 'unknown'}]
```

which shows better where to add your other clauses, and also adds a notation (`unknown`) to the result if you missed a case.

Comment: this was a tough input to work with, especially with `{ type: string | array | object }`. nice call on the `{ type: "unknown" }`

Comment: @Thankyou: the concern of course is that the example shows only a small portion of the possible complexity of the input.

Comment: exactly! this question was just within the threshold of acceptance but there are still many undefined aspects...